# content text in tooltip jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display text through jquery

```
$(function () {
  $(".outer").tooltip({
      content: "Awesome title!",
      position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" },
      content: function () {
          return $(this).prop('title');
      }
  });
});
```

html

```
<p class="outer">
    <label for="age">Your age:</label>
    <input id="age"
    title="<label id='idhere'></label>"/>
</p>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/)

how to display "Awesome title!" when mouse hover through jquery?

Comment: you had 2 content.  Just remove the second: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/11/

Comment: yes but using the second content: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/12/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give  `"Awesome title!"` to title of the input.
Here is updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I had updated your fiddler:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/2/

```
$(function () {
  $(".outer").tooltip({
      content: "Awesome title!",
      position: { my: "left+15 center", at: "right center" },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the title attribute with what you need not the `content` :

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/5/)

You are overriding the content twice :

First time :

```
 content: "Awesome title!",
```

Second time :

```
content: function () {
          return $(this).prop('title');
      }
```

Just use the second time and set the title attribute as the fiddle link. Or you can use the first time without the title attribute as you wish.... But only one of them not both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `property title` of `.outer`, you need to specify `title="Awesome title!"` to `div` having `.outer`. So updated HTML becomes:

```
<p class="outer" title="Awesome title!">
    <label for="age">Your age:</label>
    <input id="age"
    />

</p>
```

See the fiddle : "http://jsfiddle.net/Lqsb6adp/6/"